# how to write into existing xml file using php

Tags: php

Hi every one
I have an XML file, it's contain same tags like this:

```
<data>
<info><detail>first data</detail></info>
<info><detail>second data</detail></info>
<info><detail>third data</detail></info>
....
</data>
```

I want to add this:

```
<info><detail>fourth data</detail></info>
```

to my file.

and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('foo.xml');
$xml->addChild('info')->addChild('detail', 'fourth data');
file_put_contents('foo.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

Comment: @hashim, I've changed the example to load/save to a file. You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the simplexml extension for PHP

https://www.php.net/simplexml

Specifically https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php for adding the node once you have created it.