# Write to existing XML Document

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write into existing xml file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350817/how-to-write-into-existing-xml-file-using-php)

I am trying to write into an existing XML file using SimpleXML (like Matthew says in [*how to write into existing xml file using php*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350817/how-to-write-into-existing-xml-file-using-php)), except my XML file has more items (*This is NOT the actual structure of my XML file, I am just using it as an example*).

```
<Books>
<Authors>
    <WeiMengLee>
        <Book>Beginning iOS 4 Application Development</Book>
    </WeiMengLee>
</Authors>
</Books>
```

So my question is, how can I add a new "Book" to the "WeiMengLee" item using SimpleXML in PHP?

Comment: This works **exactly the same**, you just add the child to a different element. See as well [*Example #10 Adding elements and attributes*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic#example-5287)

Comment: you need to rethink your xml structure. Is it about books or authors? You seem a bit mixed up at the moment.

Comment: @vascowhite That is not what my XML file actually looks like, I was using it as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as vascowhite already stated above, rethink the structure of your xml file. anyway, here is some code, that opens the xml file, loops through all available books in the section wei meng lee and prints out their title, then adds a new book to the section and finally saves back the file to the disk. make sure the xml file is writable by the user under which your webserver executes your php scripts.

```
//read info from xml file to structured object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('bla.xml', null, true);

//loop all available books for wei meng lee
foreach( $xml->Authors->WeiMengLee->Book as $book)
{
    //print book title + newline
    print $book . "<br />";
}

//add a new book entry to your xml object
$xml->Authors->WeiMengLee->addChild("Book", "HERE GOES THE TITLE");

//save the changes back to the xml file
//make sure to set proper file access rights 
//for bla.xml on the webserver
$xml->asXml('bla.xml');
```

hope this helps 8)

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed! I just have one question, where does my xml file need to be located on my server?

Comment: Doesn't matter where it's located, as long as you give the right path to it relative from the script calling it, as in: "../../my-xml-files/books/book-collection.XML"

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I have been attempting to save the edit to the xml file using $xml->asXML('bla.xml'); and it won't edit the file. I have changed the Permissions on the file so that everyone can read and write. Is there any reason this wouldn't be working?

Comment: I can't think of anything except the fileaccess rights of the webserver-user (i. e. www-data) which is used to execute your php scripts. check the log files for an error message. what does it say? 

placing the xml file: lets say you have a file called index.php which holds the code above. then place your bla.xml file in the same directory. double check that the file is writable. if you have shell access to the webserver use `chmod 777 bla.xml`. if you are only connecting with a ftp client, right click the file and find the file access settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide if your xml is about books or about authors.

If it is about books, then it should look something like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>Beginning iOS 4 Application Development</title>
        <author>WeiMengLee</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

You can then add a new book like this:-

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("filename.xml", null, true);

$book = $xml->addChild('book');
$book->addChild('title', 'Another Book');
$book->addChild('Author', 'WeiMengLee');
$xml->asXML('filename.xml');
```

Output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>Beginning iOS 4 Application Development</title>
        <author>WeiMengLee</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Another Book</title>
        <Author>WeiMengLee</Author>
    </book>
</books>
```

If, on the other hand your xml is about authors, then it should look something like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authors>
    <author>
        <name>WeiMengLee</name>
        <books>
            <book>Beginning iOS 4 Application Development</book>
        </books>
    </author>
</authors>
```

and you would add another book like this:-

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("filename.xml", null, true);

foreach($xml as $author){
    if($author->name == 'WeiMengLee'){
        $weimenglee = $author;
    }
}

$weimenglee->books->addChild('book', 'Another book');

$xml->asXML('filename.xml');
```

Output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authors>
    <author>
        <name>WeiMengLee</name>
        <books>
            <book>Beginning iOS 4 Application Development</book>
            <book>Another book</bmook>
        </books>
    </author>
</authors>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have one more question though, where would the "filename.xml" file need to be located on my server? Or can the "filename.xml" be changed to the link (www.notarealwebsite.com/filename.xml)?

Comment: The xml file can sit anywhere that is accessible to PHP. A url such as you describe is also acceptable, see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php

Comment: I have been attempting to save the edit to the xml file using $xml->asXML('bla.xml'); and it won't edit the file. I have changed the Permissions on the file so that everyone can read and write. Is there any reason this wouldn't be working?